# Packing and unpacking of data with bit operations in C

Tags: c

I trying do packing and unpacking of data with bit operations in C.
My expectation is if I enter 4 inputs as 1, 2, 3, 4 then output should be 1234.
But I am not getting output as expected. Please let me know What is wrong in my code or my expected output is itself is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displabits(int input)
{
    int mask=0x1, i;
    for (i=31; i>=0; i--)
    {
        mask = 1 << i;
        putchar((input & mask)? '1' : '0');
       if(i%8 == 0)
           putchar(' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, packed_output=0, mask=0x1, p=0, q=0, r=0, s=0, temp;
    printf("Enter first character\r\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    displabits(a);
    printf("Enter second character\r\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    displabits(b);
    printf("Enter third character\r\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    displabits(c);
    printf("Enter fourth character\r\n");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    displabits(d);
    a = a << 24;
    displabits(a);
    b = b << 16;
    displabits(b);
    c = c << 8;
    displabits(c);
    /* Packing data start */
    packed_output = packed_output | a;
    packed_output = packed_output | b;
    packed_output = packed_output | c;
    packed_output = packed_output | d;
    printf("packed_output = %d\r\n", packed_output);
    printf("packed_output in 32 bit format formar");
    displabits(packed_output);
    /* Packing data end */

    /* Unpacking data start */
    mask = ~(~0<<8)<<(31-8+1);
    p = packed_output & mask;
    p = p >> 24;
    mask = ~(~0<<8)<<(23-8+1);
    q = packed_output & mask;
    q = q >> 16;
    mask = ~(~0<<8)<<(15-8+1);
    r = packed_output & mask;
    r = r >> 8;
    mask = ~(~0<<8)<<(7-8+1);
    s = packed_output & mask;
    printf("unpacked output's are as follows\r\n");
    printf("first character = %d\r\n", p);
    printf("first character in bit format\r\n");
    displabits(p);
    printf("second character = %d\r\n", q);
    printf("second character in bit format\r\n");
    displabits(q);
    printf("third character = %d\r\n", r);
    printf("third character in bit format\r\n");
    displabits(r);
    printf("fourth character = %d\r\n", s);
    printf("fourth character in bit format\r\n");
    displabits(s);
    /* Unpacking data end */    
    return 0;
}
```

I have put packing and unpacking logic inside same codebase.

Comment: I would shift first and then mask: `p = (packed_output >> 24) & 0xff`. Also, it's better to use `unsigned int` when doing bit manipulations.

Comment: Note that shifting and masking `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` won't end up with decimal 1234.  You might end up with hexadecimal 0x01020304 with your present code — as long as none of the numbers is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you perform operation in different bases. That is why you get an unexpected answer. `n << p` is binary arithmetic, which actually equals to `n * (2 ^ p)`. However, what's you want is `n * (10 ^ r)`. So, if you want to get your answer in human readable form you need to a regular decimal arithmetic, something like:

```
a = a * 1000;
b = b * 100;
c = c * 10;
packed_output += a;
packed_output += b;
packed_output += c;
packed_output += d;
```